# How do I check the type parameter in Dart using Generics?

Tags: dart, generics, types

Consider the following snippet:

```dart
class A {}

class B extends A {}

T? f<T extends A>() {
  print(T is A);
  if (T is A) return A() as T;
  if (T is B) return B() as T;
}

void main() {
  final A? a = f();
  final B? b = f();
  print(a); // null
  print(b); // null
}
```

I have a function where I need the check what the generic type is that's passed as `T` and execute specific code.

The problem is, the `runtimeType` of `T` is `_Type` making the if statements `false` on all conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `is` operator is used to check if an object is compatible with a given interface. This is not what you want in your example since `T` is going to be a `Type`. Instead, you want to compare a `Type` with another `Type` and check if they are equal. The operator for that is `==`:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

T? f<T extends A>() {
  print(T == A);
  if (T == A) return A() as T;
  if (T == B) return B() as T;
}

void main() {
  final A? a = f();
  final B? b = f();
  print(a); // Instance of 'A'
  print(b); // Instance of 'B'
}
```